# how to show value using ng-options

Tags: json, angularjs

My object is

```
$scope.Data = { "lineList" : [
    "apple",
    "banana",
    "orange"]
}
```

how can I show these elements in ng=option. Below didn't work.

```
<select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-options="selectedLine as selectedLine.lineList for selectedLine in Data">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to display "Apple", "Orange", "Banana"... you simply just have to do this.

Your currtent data model

```
$scope.Data = { "lineList" : [
"apple",
"banana",
"orange"]
```

}

The Fix

```
<select ng-model="selecteditem" ng-options="selectedLine as selectedLine for selectedLine in Data['lineList']">
```